# Create .exe-file from an Action<String[]> object

Tags: c#, compilation, exe

A console application .exe-file is, basically, an action that takes a number of string parameters (command line arguments, presented to Main() as a string array) and does some stuff.

An Action (or Action>) is an action that takes a number of string parameters and does some stuff.

If I have an .exe-file, it's quite simple to create an Action-object from it, like this:

```
Action<String[]> a = args => <start external process, using args as arguments>
```

But is there a way to go the other way, that is, if I have an Action object, can I make a console application .exe-file from it? Preferably as self-contained as possible (that is, an .exe-file containing all the code encapsulated by the Action-object, without relying on my original .exe-file, .dll-files etc).

Edit: To clarify a bit: My application is a machine learning classification application, which reads some input, processes them in some way, resulting in some classifier (e.g., a neural network with trained weights). Now I'd like to output the resulting classifier (the neural network, or whatever) into a stand-alone exe-file, which will be used later for testing or demonstration. My solution so far is to output the classifier object to a file (using, for the time being, a binary serialization), and then have a different console application that can read this file and use it to classify new data.

However, the problem with this approach (apart from being a bit cumbersome, since I have to distribute both the exe-file and the classifier file), is that it is fragile. This is a research project, and the classifier code changes a lot. Therefore, if I have a classifier file created from my NeuralNetworkClassifier class (say) last week, it may not work next week, since the NeuralNetworkClassifier class (or other classes it depends on) may have changed. Therefore, a self-contained .exe-file, which contains all the neural network code, in addition to the learned weight values, would make our system a lot more robust.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want to achieve with this. Could you give an example of what the input would be, and what you would expect as output?

Comment: Actually, I figured there would be some generic way of doing this, therefore I didn't add much detail to my question. But I will update with some more details, to make it more clear.

Comment: Sure you can do it, you just need to write the code for a console program that wraps an Action object.

Comment: You wan to generate exe file from your code? `Emit` is that what you are looking for